# Using Excel VBA "Save As PDF" to add print area to sheets defined in an array

Tags: arrays, excel, pdf, range, vba

I have working code that creates a PDF file that I have put together from answers here (much appreciated!) and elsewhere but there are 2 parts missing:

1. the ability to add **other** print areas not defined in a sheet.
2. the ability to use checkboxes on a master sheet to select which sheet to PDF
3. The established / set print areas on each sheet need to remain for normal printing.

The code below works for the **array** defined sheets (the sheets have print ranges set):

- I currently set the array of sheets
- I create the file name based on the workbook
- I make the directory the same as the workbook
- I then use a windows standard save as dialog box with the ability to cancel (code gracefully exits)
- I have error coding just in case.

I appreciate your help!

```
Sub SaveSheetsAsPDF_Lender()

    Dim wksAllSheets As Variant
    Dim wksSheet1 As Worksheet
    Dim strFilename As String, strFilepath As String

On Error GoTo errHandler


    Set wksSheet1 = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet 'ActiveSheet  'ThisWorkbook.Sheets("rsrvs")
    wksAllSheets = Array("initial", "apt", "rsrvs", "proj", "bond2", "refi", "amort2", "su2", "sum2")
    strFilepath = Application.ActiveWorkbook.Path

With wksSheet1
    strFilename = Left(ThisWorkbook.Name, (InStrRev(ThisWorkbook.Name, ".", -1, vbTextCompare) - 1)) 'remove the excel EXTENSION to add PDF
    strFilename = strFilepath & "\" & strFilename & ".pdf"
End With


With Excel.Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogSaveAs)

    Dim i As Integer
    For i = 1 To .Filters.Count
        If InStr(.Filters(i).Extensions, "pdf") <> 0 Then Exit For
    Next i

    .FilterIndex = i
    .InitialFileName = strFilename
    .Title = "Select Folder and File Name to save"

    If CBool(.Show) Then
        strFilename = .SelectedItems.Item(.SelectedItems.Count)
    Else
        MsgBox "You cancelled the SAVE. A PDF file was NOT created.", vbExclamation, "PDF NOT Created."
        Exit Sub
    End If

        ThisWorkbook.Sheets(wksAllSheets).Select 'select tabs to save.
        If strFilename <> "False" Then
            wksSheet1.ExportAsFixedFormat _
                      Type:=xlTypePDF, _
                      Filename:=strFilename, _
                      Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
                      IncludeDocProperties:=True, _
                      IgnorePrintAreas:=False, _
                      OpenAfterPublish:=True  ' **IF** OpenAfterPublish:=FALSE then activate msgbox

        '' **IF** OpenAfterPublish:=FALSE then activate msgbox

        End If
        wksSheet1.Select    'Make sure all the worksheets are NOT left selected

End With 'part of the overwrite code above


exitHandler:
    Exit Sub
errHandler:
    wksSheet1.Select  'Make sure all the worksheets are NOT left selected
    MsgBox "Could not create PDF file" & vbCrLf & "Contact Marc ASAP."
    Resume exitHandler

wksSheet1.Select  'Make sure all the worksheets are NOT left selected
End Sub
```

Comment: I have no information on how to set the print area of each sheet. And it is unclear whether you want to make each sheet a single document or an individual document for each sheet.

Comment: Hi. The sheets in the array [ "initial", "apt", "rsrvs", "proj", "bond2", "refi", "amort2", "su2", "sum2" ] all have default print areas that need to be kept for real paper printing. **But...** I need to be able to add additional print areas from some of those sheets that WOULD be added to the PDF. All sheets go to 1 pdf file. The code above works for that just how do I add more "PAGES" in the PDF that are from coded print areas?

Comment: Hi Everyone... just checking in to see if there might be a solution code to this problem. THANKS